# Create Database Tables on Plugin Activation hook

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, mysql

My function which have code for table creation

```
   function hotel_install() {
        $path=ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php';
        require_once ($path);

        global $wpdb;
        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

        $sql_create_table = "CREATE TABLE '.$wpdb->prefix .'booking' (
          `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
          `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
          `f_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
          `l_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
          `add` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
          `city` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
          `state` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
          `postal_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `country` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
          `phone` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `email` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
          `payment_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `additional_res` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
          `check_in` date NOT NULL,
          `check_out` date NOT NULL,
          `total_nights` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `total_rooms` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `numofadult` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `numofchild` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `room_num` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `room_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `paid_amount` int(11) NOT NULL
     ) $charset_collate; ";
 require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql_create_table );



    }
```

My activation hook Code .

```
register_activation_hook(  __FILE__, array( $this, 'hotel_install' ) );
```

Meanwhile i followed fully standardize way But i am not getting any error nor  i m getting any error.

Comment: see if this works http://pastebin.com/AVj4dr2w ( otherwise check with your activation hook, try getting the function to work )

Comment: Sorry But your link isn't working for me . Kindly purpose some solution here